# Handling Compost with Bare Hands?

Tags: compost

I just realized I did this today. I usually wear gloves but today I was starting a lasagna garden (at least the base of it) and i got some bagged compost to spread over cardboard and I just spread it around with my hands.

I did promptly wash them off with soap and water when I was done....but afterwards I was like "oh crap" (It was some of that miracle gro natures care stuff).

Anyways Im just a bit worried...I didn't have any cuts on my hands that I know of...but still.

is this something to worry about?

Comment: Why did you decide to do a lasagna garden?  No till, No fertilizer is complete bunk as far as I am concerned.  If you could explain what it  is you are doing and why in your garden we could help you with the big picture.  What is this Miracle Grow Natures Care Stuff?  I do not think you need to be worried about toxic chemistry for your skin or your cuts being a problem.  Love to hear the ingredients on the label of your 'compost'...and we can go from there.

Comment: It doesn't really list ingredients on the bag but it's supposed to be "organic"...who knows whats actually in it.

Comment: I hate the word 'organic'...even the word 'natural'!  It guarantees nothing and can mean anything.  You should be just fine.  I have a terrible time wearing gloves and love the feel of soil.  Our skin is a very high tech organ keeping bad stuff out and good stuff in.  Pesticides are a different story.  Always wear protection.  Be careful with 'trends' in the garden world...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Legionella is really the main worry and if just wash your hands you should be fine. Legionella is mainly breathed in as you work with compost, and potting mixes.

See https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/37141/1894

Comment: I've heard it's actually pretty uncommon to actually get sick from it, since most people are exposed to it anyways. The compost itself was damp-ish so it wasn't really dusty at all thankfully

Answer (score 4):

Many of us do this all the time.  With the increasing use of composted garden waste in commercial composts, the biggest hazards appear to become like those of home-made compost: splinters and other sharp things that have made it through the process unaffected.

Comment: Commercial compost is scary.  You have absolutely no idea what the ingredients are.  At least you KNOW what you've put in your own compost. Splinters, rocks, chunks of whatever are no big deal in the compost pile.

Comment: @stormy yes, though I seem to find broken glass in my home-made surprisingly often given that I dont recall breaking glass in the garden.